# CSS3 Borders (Arrows) - Possibility of "two" arrows in one div?

Tags: css

i have a PSD-Layout to develope and there are some things like "cards" and i was curious if i could do that without images and only with CSS3-Borders.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3Qvc.png (how these boxes should look like)

the "inset"-arrow should be transparent (because there is a fullscreen background-image behind the "cards").

i tried playing around with cssarrowplease.com but couldn't get it to work, so i wanted to ask if it's possible at all?

and if yes: how? i tried several things at cssarrowplease.com (in developer console) but couldn't add more than one arrow to the box and the transparency also doesn't work.

any help is appreciated!

Comment: i'm not even asking for code in the first place. i'm asking if its possible. i know how to make simple arrows / speechbubbles with pseudoelements after/before. but i want to know if you can actually add TWO arrows and one inset with transparency and IF yes HOW.

Comment: Yes, but you are still supposed to try FIRST. Otherwise, you ARE asking for us to code it for you.

Comment: ...as it happens...I'd use SVG and clipping/masks

Comment: thank you anyway. i'm not quite into SVG stuff so i will stick to background-images because it seems it's not possible without images. and bg-images are way easier for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body{
  background-color:gray;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- The best solution to this is to build polygons with SVG, like this -->

<svg height="300" width="400">
  <polygon points="0 100,200 100,200 0,0 0,50 50" 
  style="fill:white;stroke:#0c6868;stroke-width:6" />
</svg>
```

Comment: awesome work, thank you. now i'd have to learn about SVG-drawing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be possible. In order to get the transparent effect on the inset arrow, you will have to create an image that is the rectangle from the top of the card to the bottom of the card, and from the point of the inset arrow to the right edge of the card (when the inset arrow is on the left side of the card). You would then align this to the left side of the middle card area. This image would need to be a png to include the transparency information.

Note, however, that getting text to wrap around the inset naturally will not be possible with css.

Comment: so without background/border-images it won't be possible to use the transparency. right? too sad. the wrapping around the inset is not a problem, would just add padding of the inset-arrows width.

Comment: No, you don't have to use a background image. You can simply use `position: absolute` on an `<img>` tag and move it into place. The middle area with text can be accomplished with a regular background and top/bottom border.

Comment: well what i meant was: it's not possible without images. i wanted a clean css3 solution without any images (doesn't matter if absolute img-elements or background-images)

Comment: Yes, definitely not possible without images.

Comment: well, too sad. but thank you. then i can use background images in the first place, that would be easier.